# I am trying to produce seasonal averages of visibility using already calculated monthly averages, but struggling

Tags: mysql

I have 70+ years of hourly visibility data that I have already calculated into a monthly average.  I now need to produce seasonal averages of DJF, MAM, JJA, SON (seasonal average meaning DEC, JAN, FEB as one average and MAR, APR, MAY, the next and so on) for each of those years.  Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to go about this using MySQL Workbench?

I essentially need 4 separate columns of the above mentioned months visibility.  Is there something I can do under the GROUP BY function like grouping by a set or anything else?

This is what I have used to get the monthly averages but I'm not sure how to

```
SELECT date, avg(lowest_visibility) FROM b16.hourly
GROUP BY year(date), month(date)
ORDER BY year(date), month(date) asc
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Update:  I have completed this task using pivot tables and tediously changing the cells to make sure I have the correct December in my DJF seasonal average, but I would still like any guidance how to do this again in the future.

Comment: Can I suggest you explain what you are trying to do without jargon or acronym

Comment: Yes, absolutely you can!  The seasonal averages I am referring to would be Dec, Jan, Feb as one average for a year.  The Dec would actually be from the year before so for example.  December of 1942, then January and February of 1943.  The MAM would be March, April, and May.  JJA = June, July August and SON = September, October, November.  I will update my post so it is more clear.  Sorry for the confusion, first-time poster here.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the input data.  You really want `AVG(lowest)`; that seems like a strange metricl. I'll help you to do the math to break the datetimes into seasons and do the group-by and the 4 columns.  It may involve a subquery to compute the averages in a single column and an outer query to "pivot" the them into 4 columns.

Answer (score 0):

May not be any better than the query you have (who knows?)

In query union to ignore DEC in it's year and union to a query which pushes the DEC year forward

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;
create table t
(dt date, val int);

insert into t values
('2019-12-01',10),
('2020-01-01',25),
('2020-06-01',10),
('2020-10-01',10),
('2020-12-01',10);

select  yyyy,
            sum(djfsum) / sum(djfcnt) dfj ,
            sum(mamcnt) / sum(mamcnt) mam ,
            sum(jjasum) / sum(jjacnt) jja ,
            sum(sonsum) / sum(soncnt) son
from
(
select  year(t.dt) yyyy,
          sum(case when MONTH(dt) IN(1,2)     then val else 0 end) djfsum,
          sum(case when MONTH(dt) IN(1,2)     then 1   else 0 end) djfcnt,
          sum(case when MONTH(dt) IN(3,4,5)   then val else 0 end) mamsum,
          sum(case when MONTH(dt) IN(3,4,5)   then 1   else 0 end) mamcnt,
          sum(case when MONTH(dt) IN(6,7,8)   then val else 0 end) jjasum,
          sum(case when MONTH(dt) IN(6,7,8)   then 1   else 0 end) jjacnt,
          sum(case when MONTH(dt) IN(9,10,11) then val else 0 end) sonsum,
          sum(case when MONTH(dt) IN(9,10,11) then 1   else 0 end) soncnt
from t
where month(dt) <> 12
group by yyyy
union 
select year(dt) + 1,
         sum(val) as djfsum,
         sum(1)   as djfcnt,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0
from  t
where  month(dt) = 12
group  by year(dt) + 1
) a
group by yyyy
;

+------+---------+------+---------+---------+
| yyyy | dfj     | mam  | jja     | son     |
+------+---------+------+---------+---------+
| 2020 | 17.5000 | NULL | 10.0000 | 10.0000 |
| 2021 | 10.0000 | NULL |    NULL |    NULL |
+------+---------+------+---------+---------+
2 rows in set, 4 warnings (0.002 sec)
```